# HTTPS GET request using existing browser session in Java

Tags: java, https, get

I have a usecase where I have a set of HTTPS GET requests which are password protected, I want to access the Request body but without passing username/password everytime, instead using the my Chrome browser session.

Here is how I am trying by creating new HTTP connection everytime giving my credentials, which is not suggestible and also slow.

```
String url = "<Request URL>";
URL obj = new URL(url);

String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("<username>:<password>").getBytes());
System.out.println("Encoded Credential String:==>"+encoding);

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

System.out.println("Response connection string: "+con.toString());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Can someone please provide me directions, how I should proceed if my implementation is in Java ?

Comment: How do you authorize? Its seams you want to authorize via basic Auth? Is the server supporting authorization via basic auth? Or do you want to use cookies? Please explain, what excaclty you are up to do

Comment: @YingYang: I want to use cookies, as I understand that Basic Auth is not reliable and suggested.

Comment: You only want to send a cookie to the authendicate server, or do you first have to authorize and receive a cookie? For sending, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761273/how-to-send-a-cookie-in-a-urlconnection To receive, you have to use "getHeaderFieldKey" See here: http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/URL_Connection_Address/Get_and_set_cookie_through_URLConnection_in_Java.htm

Comment: is it a pure java or an android application?

Answer (score 0):

Using basic auth is really not any "slower" in any meaningful sense.

However, If you want to use cookies then you can just do

```
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "cookiename=cookievalue");
```

instead of `Authorization` header you currently have. This is assuming you know the cookie name and value to send. You can inspect Chrome HTTP traffic to get that.