# Need help to download a pdf file from a url. The file access is restricted

Tags: java

I am trying to validate the contents of a pdf letter for my test automation. For that, first I am trying to download the pdf file to my local machine and validate. But I am not able to download the file properly with Java.
The pdf is present as an embedded document in a page which requires me to log in first. The html looks like below

```html
<td colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top;" id="frameCell_24743998"><iframe id="viewFrame_24743998" src="https://wewewe.net/ewr/ww/desk/ViewQCWalzPDFAction.do?recordId=24743998&amp;we=we&amp;partitionId=16515&amp;Id=1561024580039s79n0a" height="550" width="800" style="width: 1254px;"></iframe><br></td>
```

So I have got the url and tried to download the file using

```java
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("https://wewewe.net/ewr/ww/desk/ViewQCWalzPDFAction.do?recordId=24743998&amp;we=we&amp;partitionId=16515&amp;Id=1561024580039s79n0a"), new File("C:\\workspace\\dfdf\\dfdffddf\\dd.pdf"));
```

But it is showing

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
>   Exception.

So is this because I haven't logged in to the application and trying to download. Is there any other way to download it?

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that the URL you use in your code is deemed a **Potential Security Risk**.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to download it?

That very much depends on how exactly that web page is built.

It might for example be possible to use **cookies** with your Java code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761273/how-to-send-a-cookie-in-a-urlconnection) for some instructions how to do that. Meaning: you can enable your java code to appear "authorised".

If all of that doesn't work (and **adapting** the server to be allow "programmatic" access to such files isn't an option), then you could use automation tools such as *selenium* to do a "browser like" connection+download. See [there](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver) for guidance.